# How to keep the reference to the original object that invoked a jquery plug in?

Tags: jquery, jquery-plugins

I am creating a jquery plugin that adds a help text icon next to the element its being called on. How do I get a reference to the original input/textarea object on which the plugin method was callled?

Here is the code:

```
 <input text name="name" data-help-text="Enter your name here" class="helpon">
    <input text name="age" data-help-text="Enter your age here" class="helpon">
    <textarea name="experience" data-help-text="Enter a short summary of your experience" class="helpon"> </textarea>


    <script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).on("ready", function() {

        $.fn.showHelp = function() {
            return this.each(function() {
                self = $(this)
                var icon = $('<icon class="icon-question" data-help-text="icon here">?</i>')
                icon.on("click", function(){ 
                 //how do i get a reference to the input/textarea here on which this? 
                    alert( self.data("help-text") )
                });
                self.after(icon);
            });
        };


      $('.helpon').showHelp();
    });


    </script>
```

how do i get a reference to the input/textarea on the icon click event? self is referring to the last object in the objects array (textarea in this case)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to give a scope to the `self` variable:

```
$.fn.showHelp = function() {
            return this.each(function() {
                var self = $(this)
                var icon = $('<icon class="icon-question" data-help-text="icon here">?</i>')
                icon.on("click", function(){ 
                 //how do i get a reference to the input/textarea here on which this? 
                    alert( self.data("help-text") )
                });
                self.after(icon);
            });
        };


      $('.helpon').showHelp()
```

Comment: How do I do that? Not sure your answer mentions how?

Comment: I just declared `self` with the `var` keyword, just inside your each function. This will limit the scope of self to the each loop

Answer (score 0):

You can use the event object to get the target element.

```
var icon = $('<icon class="icon-question" data-help-text="icon here">?</i>')
icon.on("click", function(){ 
    // you can use the target of the event object 
    alert( $(e.target).data("help-text") )
});
```

you can get details over [here](http://api.jquery.com/event.target/)